# How should I go about creating a generic Scene object for managing VBO data?

Tags: opengl, vbo, vao

To simplify managing multiple types of data with different shaders and textures, I thought about creating a generic `Scene` object (is there a name for this?) which would allow me to pre-configure how I want to render something, and how the data changes. Let me give an example:

*Everything  below is in the context of a 2D top-down game*

- Some parts are completely static, e.g. the background, and their geometry never changes.
- Then there'd be a "NPC" layer, which can change on almost every single frame, uses different shaders.
- Last but not least, there's a UI layer, which sits on top of everything else.

Some of these parts would probably be split into multiple subparts, such as parts rendered as `GL_TRIANGLE_FAN`, and other parts rendered as `GL_LINE_STRIP`, etc. To avoid duplicating lots of setup/generate geometry/render phases, it would seem logical to wrap this in something that can be configured, such as:

```
Scene s;
Batch b1 = s.create_batch(somehow_specify_shaders_etc);
generate_background_geometry(b1);

Batch b2 = s.create_batch(somehow_specify_other_shaders_and_VAO);     

// game loop
while (true) {
  // this would generate/update the NPC geometry on the fly
  b2.process_input(gather_user_input());

  for (Batch b: s) b.render();
}
```

Now what if I wanted to specify different texture bindings for each batch? Or different shaders?

**Is there a general pattern for managing geometry data like this?**